# Require but dont break out of sandbox environment - luajit

Tags: lua, luajit, sol3

Is there a way to run a script in a sandbox environment to not pollute global state, but still be able to require"someluafile" in which global vars get set for said environment and NOT the global state

```
-- main script
local moduleXY = require"moduleXY"
v = 0
moduleXY.setV()

-- moduleXY
local function setV ()
  v = 42
end

local moduleXY = {
   setV = setV
}

return moduleXY
```

so that after the call the states v is nil and envs v is set to 42
(instead of state v being 42 and envs 0)

luajit (so 5.1), cpp binding sol3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua 5.1 uses `setfenv` to change the environment of a function. Here's an example.

```
local moduleXY = require"moduleXY"
v = 0

env = setmetatable({}, {__index = _G}) -- create an environment
setfenv(moduleXY.setV, env) -- change the environment
moduleXY.setV()
print(v)     -- 0
print(env.v) -- 42

setfenv(moduleXY.setV, _G)  -- revert the environment
moduleXY.setV()
print(v)     -- 42
```

---

To change the environment of the current thread use `setfenv(0)`.

```
setfenv(0, env) -- this doesn't affect loaded functions
local moduleXY = require"moduleXY" -- module is loaded in 'env' environment
moduleXY.setV()
print(env.v) -- 42

setfenv(0, getfenv()) -- revert the thread environment
require"othermodule" -- load other module in default environment
```

Comment: that's the perfect approach. thank you. but the main script is already run in an environment &  I would need to run the function from moduleXY in the same environment, not a new one.
currently my problem with require is that it breaks out of that sandbox

Comment: I've updated my answer, added an approach to change the environment of the required file.